# set to string conversion

Tags: list, set, collection

```
  Set<ID> objIDs = new Set<ID>(); //objIDs is used to store the user Id's
```

i have two id in ObjIDs,

for example: 0054E000001jEoUQAU, 0054E000001lC07QAE.

How to query the email address from `ObjIDs` and assign it `List<String>` ?

Answer (score 2):

For querying from the set of Id, use below SOQL

```
SELECT Fields from API_Name_of_Object WHERE Id IN: objIDs;
```

Using a for loop, then you can fetch the Email Address and then add it to List

Answer (score 1):

As your Id's are related to user object and you want the email field so you can simply do this

```
Set<string> emailSet = new Set<string>();
for(user U : Select email from user where Id IN: objIDs)
       emailSet.add(u.email);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get idea from the following piece of code, get iteration using for loop and get each user's email through iterated users and assign to your `List<string>`.

```
List<string> UserEmail = new List<string>();

for(User u : [select Id, Email from User where Id =: objIDs]){
    UserEmail.add(u.Email);
}
```

Hope it helps you out !!